# Check if a group of values is contained in a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, charindex

I'm trying to check if a certain column has something like:

```
SELECT Id,
CASE CHARINDEX(Name,'Value A') WHEN 0 THEN '0'
      ELSE '1'
END
FROM TABLE
```

This works for testing `Value A`; now I want to check multiple values.  For example, I'd like to check whether `Name` matches any of `Value A`, `Value B`, `Value C`. `CHARINDEX` will only allow one at a time.

There is a way to do this?

Comment: Do you want any of those at all of them?

Comment: I forget to mention I can't use contains also.

Comment: Which version of [tag:SQL-server]?

Comment: I want any of the values.  Basically I want to check if a value from a list of values matches the column value.

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id, 
    iif (Name LIKE '%Value A%' OR Name LIKE '%Value B%', 1, 0) AS IsContainsTheValue
  FROM Table;
```

This assumes that the values are static, which seems to be the case from your question.

**Edit** for exact match

```
Declare @matchValues Table (Value varchar(100));
-- maybe you could pass a table from the application??

SELECT id, 
    iif (v.Value Is Not Null, 1, 0) AS IsContainsTheValue
  FROM Table AS t
  LEFT JOIN @matchValues AS v On t.Name = v.Value;
```

Comment: This works for me, I just need to build that iif statement outside my query because the number of values could be dynamic. thanks a lot

Comment: Can I add a IN() in the select statement?

Comment: `In ()` only works for exact matches, no `%` wild cards.

Comment: Are the unknown number of values coming from a table in the db or from the application?

Comment: It comes from the application

Comment: I don't need the wild card, it can be exactly Value A, Value B